# push to a remote repo in git

Tags: git, version-control

I have a remote repo and I want to be able to push to that repo and deploy the code. So, when I execute `git push origin branch`, it should push the branch to the repo and the post-receive hooks should deploy the changes. The problem is-

1. For deploying the code, I need to checkout to that branch, so when I push again it throws an error about pushing to the checked out branch. If I checkout to say master every time in pre-receive hook, there will be problems like uncommitted changes, stashing the changes and so on.

I can't make the current repo a bare repo and so I want to create a bare repo (by cloning the current repo) on the fly and push the branch to that repo instead.

Can I create a bare repo on the fly and somehow divert the push to that repo instead of the current repo?

Comment: when was the error occurs, pre-receive hook or post-receive hook? And what's  the error message?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a bare repo for the current repo by add "--bare" option:

```
git clone --bare my_project my_project.git
```

And then put the bare repo on your Git server if needed, refer to this link for details: [Git on the Server - Getting Git on a Server](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-on-the-Server-Getting-Git-on-a-Server).

And then, in your local repo, run [git remote set-url](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-remote) command to update the remote repo to the bare repo.